# Playing in AVPlayer causes UI freezing

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, avplayeritem

I am doing an iOS application with a video player in it. I have to change my video URL each time user switch it view angle. But when I am switching to a new URL my UI gets freezed for some time. Following is my code for switching video URL function.

```
    // Create the AVPlayer using the playeritem
    m_pMoviePlayer =   [AVPlayer playerWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:pUrl]];

    NSError *_error = nil;
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: &_error];

    m_pMoviePlayer.allowsExternalPlayback = NO;

    // You can play/pause using the AVPlayer object
    [m_pMoviePlayer play];

    [self registerMoviePlayerObservers];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: before playing next Url  'pause' the current.

Comment: But when I am initialising for the first time also, I am getting a UI freeze

Comment: [self registerMoviePlayerObservers] call this before  [m_pMoviePlayer play];

Comment: do you need to set the audio session category every time?

Comment: I have tried that. But no luck.

Comment: Can I initialise AVPlayer in background thread ?